# Assignment "=" operator in VB.NET 1.1

Tags: vb.net, .net-1.1

I'm "cloning" objects in my code.  For instance:

```
objClone = objOriginal
```

My question is:

1. Does the assignment operator in VB.NET 1.1 do a member-by-member copy of the objOriginal to objClone or does objClone simply point as a reference to memory referenced by objOriginal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a reference copy, if the type is a reference type (ie: classes).  If it's a value type (Structure), it will do a member by member copy.

Comment: FYI - this is the same in newer versions of VB.NET as well as C# and other .NET languages.

Answer (score 3):

What happens with the code that you show depends on what type `objOriginal` is:

- If it is a reference type, `objClone` will reference the same instance as `objOriginal`
- If it is a value type, `objClone` will be a new instance, with the same content as `objOriginal`

Note though, if it is a value type having any members being reference types, those members will reference the same instances as the original object (this is known as a *shallow copy*).

Examples:

```
Public Class Test
    Public Number As Integer
End Class

Dim objOriginal As New Test()
objOriginal.Number = 42
Dim objClone As Test
objClone = objOriginal
```

In this case, `objClone` and `objOriginal` will both reference the same instance of `Test`.

```
Public Structure Test
    Public Number As Integer
End Class

Dim objOriginal As New Test()
objOriginal.Number = 42
Dim objClone As Test
objClone = objOriginal
```

In this case, `objClone` and `objOriginal` will be different instances of `Test`, each with their own `Integer` instance in the `Number` field.

```
Public Class SomeValue
    Public Number As Integer
End Class
Public Structure Test
    Public Value As SomeValue
End Class

Dim objOriginal As New Test()
objOriginal.Value = New SomeValue()
objOriginal.Value.Number = 42
Dim objClone As Test
objClone = objOriginal
```

In this case, `objClone` and `objOriginal` will be two different instances of k, but both will reference the same instance of `SomeValue` through their Value member.

Comment: Wow! That's a messy problem to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about VB, but the C# version of assignment only does a shallow copy.
(Edit: For reference types).